# C - realloc(): invalid pointer error encoutered

Tags: c

I've been trying O(n ^2) sorting algorithm just to practice C, but have encountered this annoying "realloc(): invalid pointer" error and cannot figure out why. I've viewed other explanations but they have not helped too much.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int* removeIndex(int* list, int index, int len){
        for(int i = index; i < len - 1; i++){
            list[i] = list[i+1];
        }
        return realloc(list, len - 1);
    }

    int* sort(int* unsorted, int len){
         int* sorted = malloc(len * sizeof(int));

         for(int placement = 0; placement < len; placement++){
             int smallest_index = 0;
             int smallest = unsorted[smallest_index];
             int len_unsorted = len - placement;

             for(int i = 0; i < len_unsorted; i++){
                if (unsorted[i] < smallest){
                    smallest = unsorted[i];
                    smallest_index = i;
                }    
             }

             unsorted = removeIndex(unsorted, smallest_index, len_unsorted);
             sorted[placement] = smallest;
         }

        return sorted;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int len = 5;
        int unsorted[5] = {5,4,3,2,1};

        int* sorted = sort(unsorted, len);

        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            printf("%d\n", sorted[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

On a side note, why do I get an error if I write

```
int len = 5;
int unsorted[len] = {5,4,3,2,1};
```

so I have to force write it as `int unsorted[5] = {5,4,3,2,1};`

Cheers

Comment: Your `unsorted` is a static array. Allocate it with `malloc`.

Comment: no need for `realloc()` here at all. `return realloc(...` is an error anyways, it could return NULL, leaving your original memory intact (so you'd lose the pointer to it)

Answer (score 2):

The pointer passed to `realloc` pointing to a array with auto storage duration, which is declared and initialized in `main()`, and not pointing to a memory block previously allocated with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

From [realloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) *[emphasis added]*

> Reallocates the given area of memory. **It must be previously allocated by malloc(), calloc() or realloc()** and not yet freed with a call to free or realloc. Otherwise, the results are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the answer of H.S., I believe the sorting algorithm is ill designed. The first call to the function `removeIndex` is done with the parameters as so

```
removeIndex(unsorted, 4, 5)
```

The for loop is not entered and a reallocation is supposed to take place with `realloc(list, 4)`.

As far as I can see the sorting algorithm cannot work in general. In particular the example you gave with 5,4,3,2,1.

Try to do that with pencil and paper and you will see what I mean.